# How to get a correct method reference when performing a JMP instruction to a method that resides in a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, reflection.emit, il

I have the following code that basically creates a DynamicAssembly with 2 types with one public method each.

```
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly
                (new AssemblyName("TestAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("Main");
        var type1 = module.DefineType("type1");


        var method1 = type1.DefineMethod
                      (
                        "Method1", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), null
                      );

        var gen = method1.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var t1 = type1.CreateType();

        var createdMethod1 = t1.GetMethod("Method1");

        var type2 = module.DefineType("type2");

        var method2 = type2.DefineMethod
                      (
                        "Method2", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), null
                      );


        byte[] ilCodes = new byte[5];
        ilCodes[0] = (byte)OpCodes.Jmp.Value;
        ilCodes[1] = (byte)(createdMethod1.MetadataToken & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[2] = (byte)(createdMethod1.MetadataToken >> 8 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[3] = (byte)(createdMethod1.MetadataToken >> 16 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[4] = (byte)(createdMethod1.MetadataToken >> 24 & 0xFF);

        method2.SetMethodBody(ilCodes, ilCodes.Length, null, null, null);


        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type2.CreateType());

        obj.GetType().GetMethod("Method2").Invoke(obj, null);
```

Whenever I make a call to type2.method2() I have a JMP instruction to type1.method1().

This works like a charm, both types reside in the same assembly.

Now if I want to redirect to a type that is in another assembly how can I get the correct assembly/module reference in order the JMP instruction to succeed. If I just do like this:

```
        byte[] ilCodes = new byte[5];
        ilCodes[0] = (byte)OpCodes.Jmp.Value;
        ilCodes[1] = (byte)(methodFromOtherAssembly.MetadataToken & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[2] = (byte)(methodFromOtherAssembly.MetadataToken >> 8 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[3] = (byte)(methodFromOtherAssembly.MetadataToken >> 16 & 0xFF);
        ilCodes[4] = (byte)(methodFromOtherAssembly.MetadataToken >> 24 & 0xFF);
```

It keeps failing with IndexNotFound exception.

I want to do this with Raw IL byte instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metadata tokens are not globally unique. They are resolved in the context of the calling method's module. You need to use [GetMetadataToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkc3w40x(v=vs.110).aspx) on the module to get the proper token. Your first example works because the methods share the same module.

This will get the proper token from the dynamic module:

```
byte[] ilCodes = new byte[5];
int token = module.GetMetadataToken(methodFromOtherAssembly).Token;
ilCodes[0] = (byte)OpCodes.Jmp.Value;
ilCodes[1] = (byte)(token & 0xFF);
ilCodes[2] = (byte)(token >> 8 & 0xFF);
ilCodes[3] = (byte)(token >> 16 & 0xFF);
ilCodes[4] = (byte)(token >> 24 & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Mike what can I say? Worked Like a Boss! ☺ Excelent answer Thank you so much!!